# Rails displaying validation messages on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to validate a `data` model that `belongs_to` a `project` model. The validation works as data does not get saved if it fails the validation.

However, I can't get the `data` validation to display the correct error message from the validation on the new form.

How do I display the correct error validation messages on the `data` form?

**Form URL**
http://localhost:9080/projects/7/data/new

**Data Model:**

```
class Datum < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  validates :supplier, :item, :presence => true #need this to display error message on data form
end
```

**Project Model:**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name,:presence => true #works perfectly, displays error message on project form
  has_many :data, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :data
end
```

**Data Controller**

```
def create
  @datum = Datum.new(datum_params)
  @datum.project_id = params[:project_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @datum.save
      format.html { redirect_to project_data_path, notice: 'Created.' }
    else
      format.html {#do I need something here to redisplay the form with the errors }
    end
  end
end
```

**Data Form:**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@project, @project.data.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :supplier %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**
The closest I got to a solution is if the object doesn't save:

```
format.html { redirect_to new_project_datum_path, alert: @datum.errors }
```

But this isn't exactly what I need. Because it just returns the error msg, and the empty fields so the user has to fill out all fields again.
For some reason the redirect works, but the `render 'new'` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should render the 'new' action if the saving fails:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @datum = @project.build(datum_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @datum.save
      format.html { redirect_to project_data_path, notice: 'Created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

Also you should change your form to use the `@datum` instance variable instead building it in the form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@project, @datum]) do |f| %>
```

and the controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @datum = @project.data.build
end
```

The basic idea is that if the user arrives to the new page you create a new empty datum instance variable. The user fills out the form and posts it to the create action. If the saving fails in the create action, you keep your filled-out @datum object and render that back to the form. The @datum object will have the errors ( you can check by @datum.errors ) which you can display to the user.

Comment: You know I tried that, but it throws a:
`undefined method 'data' for nil:NilClass` and highlights: `<%= bootstrap_form_for([@project, @project.data.build]) do |f| %>`

Comment: I added more details to the answer

Comment: When I put in your edits: undefined method 'data_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc60505ab68>:0x007fc5ec4b44c0> and highlights: `<%= bootstrap_form_for([@project, @datum]) do |f| %>`

Comment: However, if I submit a valid form with `supplier` and `item` present, it works

Comment: does switching to render :new makes any difference?

Comment: Error reads: undefined method 'data_path', but doesn't it need to be 'project_data_path' since data belongs to project - I bet that's why `render :new` won't work? How would I render the :new project data?

Comment: I re-edited the answer. We did not initialized the @project variable in the create action, that is why the form builder is complaining i think